# Must GroovyTestCase methods return void?

Tags: groovy, junit3

In the docs for groovy.util.GroovyTestCase (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html) the description says "A default JUnit TestCase in Groovy. This provides a number of helper methods plus **avoids the JUnit restriction of requiring all test* methods to be void return type**.

However, when I use groovy JUnit3 code like the following, JUnit finds no tests:

```
class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    def testSomething() {
        assert 1 + 1 == 2
    }
}
```

If I change the return type of testSomething() to void (as is normal in JUnit) the test is found just fine.

Do I need to write the test differently or is the doc wrong?

Comment: looks like you're right, the method must return `void` and start with the word `test`

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the source](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.2.1/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.java/?v=source) for v 2.2.1 of `GroovyTestCase`. I believe that your assertion is correct: the doc is wrong.

I don't see any code that supports the claim, and even in the case for the `notYetImplemented` feature, the method `isPublicTestMethod` clearly looks for void (and implies the code is from JUnit itself). This last point isn't related to your code, per se, but further suggests the comment is off base.